# About the discriminant ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, dedekind-domain, discriminant

Let $E/K$ be a separable field extension of degree $n$, let $A$ be a Dedekind Domain which quotient field is $K$, and let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $E$. Then we have that the ideal generated by the discriminants $D_{E/K}(\alpha_1, \cdots , \alpha_n)$ where, $\alpha_1, \cdots , \alpha_n$ runs over all integral bases of $B$, is the discriminant ideal of $E/K$.

Ok, now, we need $E/K$ be separable because if it is not separable, then the trace is always $0$ and thus the discriminants will be zero.
But, why do we need $A$ to be a Dedekind Domain? Is it not enought to be just an integral Domain?

Thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: This is the usual setting of algebraic number theory. From what pops up in my head right now, needing A to be Dedekind has to do with the study of ideal decomposition. Indeed, in Dedekind domain, we have prime factorization of ideals which does not hold in more general rings usually. This leads to ramification theory eventually. However, I requiring A to be Dedekind is a too strong condition for ensuring the discriminant ideal to be nonzero. I think A being Dedekind is just useful to have well behaved / easy to work with ideals such as the discriminant ideal.